# ref=ts on facebook app url cause app not found error

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I've create an facebook app and it run smoothly at
https://apps.facebook.com/icoloringstar/

But the problem is: when I search my app name "icoloring star" in facebook, it link to the app at url:
https://apps.facebook.com/icoloringstar/?fb_source=search&**ref=ts**

Then facebook said that:

*App "iColoring Star" is unavailable
The app "iColoring Star" is temporarily unavailable due to an issue with its third-party developer. We are investigating the situation and apologize for any inconvenience.*

We found that url part "ref=ts" cause above problem, but really do not know why?

**Could you explain me why and how to resolve this problem?**
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your code is failing when the `ref` parameter is supplied in the request path.
I was able to repro this with any arbitrary value in the ref parameter when accessing your app

- Check your server logs and and see if you're returning a 500 error to facebook when the request comes in
- See if you have any code that parses a `ref` parameter and check it's not throwing exceptions
- Make sure your callback URL in the app settings doesn't also specify a `ref` parameter or your app may receive two values and/or fail entirely

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is my callback url contain ref param too.

Answer (score 0):

It means 'Top Search'. User enter a query into the top of search.

There are some ref parameters.. ref=bookmarks for example. I dont know the full list.

Did you put your app on Facebook App Center?